# Why does my lemon tree have multi-colored leaves and strange-looking fruit?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, lemons

The leaves on my lemon tree are yellow and white, and the fruit doesn't look normal.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site! Thanks for the question, I've never seen a lemon tree like that! I'm glad it was normal and not sick. I hope you stay around and have fun with us!

Answer (score 10):

This plant is variegated and is likely to be [Citrus limon 'Eureka Variegated Pink'](http://www.monrovia.com/plant-catalog/plants/802/pink-variegated-eureka-lemon/).

Described by the [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2005/02/02/dining/lemons-yes-but-please-dont-squeeze.html?_r=0) as

> A mutant found on an ordinary Eureka lemon tree in Burbank, Calif.,
>   around 1930, its immature fruit has green and white stripes; the older
>   fruit loses the stripes and develops flesh pigmented pink from
>   lycopene, which also colors pink grapefruit. The trees are usually
>   poor producers, perhaps because their variegated leaves are low in
>   chlorophyll.

So there is nothing wrong with your lemon tree. It is a unique curiosity.

Comment: Good one! For better lemon production, you need another one and keep this for more ornamental uses.

Comment: Yeah. I had a Pruden's Purple tomato plant wherein part of it was variegated like that last year (that isn't typical for the variety). Your tree definitely looks variegated. I believe all Fish peppers are like that naturally, though.